# What is L1, L2, L3 Cache memory in iPhone. How it related to Heap/Stack memory and number of cores in a processor(A10)

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, heap-memory, processor

I would like to know more about the process of L1,L2,L3 cache memory in iPhone. 
How it related to processor(core),Heap/Stack memory, threads etc..
How to handle it?
Elaborating with an example is more help full to understand.